# Python: Changing boolean list values

Tags: python

I've encountered some behavior that confuses me.

```
to_return = [[], False]
for i in other_list:
    value, flag = i[0], i[1]
    to_return[0].append(value)
    if flag is True and to_return[1] is False:
        to_return[1] is True
```

In other words, just change the bool to True if something I'm appending contains a True value.

Why is `to_return[1] is True` not reached in this code? And how should I update that value?

Comment: Did you mean to say: `to_return[1] = True` (in the last line)?

Comment: @SuperSaiyan apparently I did. Not enough coffee today, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

`to_return[1] is True` is simply a boolean expression. Perhaps you mean `to_return[1] = True`?

Answer (score 0):

"if smth == True" can be replaced with simple "if smth", so code will look better. If you need to check for false use "if not smth", it is equal to "if smth == False"